# Are both of these phrases grammatically correct?

Tags: phrases, phrase-choice, noun-phrases

Are both of these phrases grammatically correct?

> 1. Preparation of medicinal plant extract.

or

> 2. Preparation medicinal plant extract.

Can both be used as headings?

Comment: you need to change the order of the words for 2 : Medicinal plant extract preparation

Comment: Can't we use Preparation medicinal plant extract? is it grammatically wrong?

Comment: preparation is a noun, so 2 would be [noun]+[adjective]+[noun phrase], which isn't grammatical

Answer (score 1):

These are rather phrases than sentences but it does not matter for all practical purposes.

The first is correct:

> Preparation of medicinal plant extract.

In the second, you need to change word order as someone has already suggested in the comments:

> Medicinal plant extract preparation.

However, it still sounds a bit awkward as such a long subject is difficult to comprehend, so if I were you **I would go with the first sentence.**

Generally, such transformations between *A of B* and *B/(adjective from) B A* often exist:

> Bombers of WWII <-> WWII bombers.
>     States of Europe <-> European states
>     The US constitution ratification <-> The ratification of the US constitution